# Connected Graph question

Tags: graph-theory

I was given the next question:

I'm given an un-directed full graph $G$ with 20 verticals.I need to prove that after removing 18 of the edges the graph is still connected.
  I tried with induction but failed doing so, any help will be helpful!

p.s.: I'm not allowed to use the Pigeonhole principle.

Comment: Given two vertices $a,b$ there are $19$ independent paths from $a$ to $b$: the direct edge $a\to b$ and for each of the other $18$ vertices $v$, a path $a\to v\to b$. As $19>18$, removing $18$ edges cannot destroy all these paths. It is a pity that this uses pigeon-hole ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* use induction to show

**Proposition.** Let $G$ be a graph obtained from the complete graph on $n$ vertices by removing at most $\le n-2$ edges. Then $G$ is connected.

*Proof.* If $n\le 2$, the claim is vacuously true.
Assume $n>2$ and let $v$ be any of the vertices of $G$. 
if $\rho(v)=n-1$, then trivially $G$ is connected. 
So assume $\rho(v)<n-1$, i.e., at least one of the removed edges ends in $v$.
Then the graph $G'$ obtained from $G$ by removing vertex $v$ and its incident edges) has $n-1$ vertices and is the complete graph on these with at most $n-3$ edges removed. By induction hypothesis, it is connected. To show that $G$ is also connected, it suffices to show that there exists at least one edge $vw$ with $w\in G'$, but this follows from $\rho(v)\ge (n-1)-(n-2)=1$. *(This last step just barely avoids using the pigeon-hole principle)*  $\square$

Comment: Thank you so much! I have a question. Your answer in the comments isn't correct? (because you chose to add this comment)

Comment: @Lola the answer in the comments is correct but uses the pigeonhole principle